# Identifying HTML tags with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I'm using iTextSharp to generate a pdf from an html template. I have this working but now I'm having some issues styling the pdf.

I want `h2` and `h3` tags to be underlined, but not `h1` tags.

When my html is parsed, it seems that the parsed elements are either being loaded as `Paragraph`s or `PdfPTable`s.

The code:

```
    var parsedHtmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(transformableTemplate.Body), _styles, _interfaceProps);
    foreach (var htmlElement in parsedHtmlElements)
    {
        var paragraph = htmlElement as Paragraph;
        if (paragraph != null)
        {
               var border = new ParagraphUnderline(new Color(0xd1, 0xd4, 0xd3), 1);
                            writer.PageEvent = border;
                            border.setActive(true);
                            paragraph.SpacingBefore = 20;
                            document.Add(paragraph);
                            border.setActive(false);
                            continue;
        }

        var table =  as PdfPTable;
        if (table != null)
        {
            table.SpacingAfter = 20;
            document.Add(table);
            continue;
        }

        document.Add(htmlElement as IElement);
    }
```

Is there any way to find out, for each Paragraph, what the corresponding tag was? I have tried setting classes and attributes in the HTML, but they seem to be ignored by the parser.

Comment: Not an answer, but don't use `HTMLWorker`. It is deprecated. Use `XMLWorker` instead.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasseI I believe XMLWorker was introduced in iText 5. I have to develop against 4 because that's what it will be using when it's live.

Comment: Either that, or you give away your source code to your end users and you can use iText for free under the AGPL license. But okay, that's your call. It's just that any answer might be targeted at `XMLWorker` because none of the people who wrote iText still know how `HTMLWorker` works.

Comment: I understand. It's not my call though. Also, the Pdf Generation will be a tiny part of a larger application, and we can't open-source it just for that. ...  I suppose I could grab the code to HtmlWorker and extend it.